# How to perform a double strikethrough on text with inline css?

Tags: html, css

I want my text to have 2 strikethroughs but using **only inline CSS**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Double Strikeout a Text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395890/how-to-double-strikeout-a-text-in-html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `del` tag with `text-decoration-style: double` for a double strikethrough.

```html
<del style="text-decoration-style: double;">Text with double strike through</del>
```

To apply a double strikethrough on normal text inside a `span` or other tag, you can use `text-decoration: line-through` and `text-decoration-style: double`.

```html
<span style="text-decoration: line-through; text-decoration-style: double;">Text with double strikethrough</span>
```

See also: [`text-decoration-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style), [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Answer (score 0):

you can use gradient:

```html
<span style="background:linear-gradient(#000,#000) 50% 35%/100% 1px no-repeat,linear-gradient(#000,#000) 50% 65%/100% 1px no-repeat;">some text to strike</span>
```